# How to model this as a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have the following classes:

```
public class A
{
    public string P1 {get;set;}
    public string P2 {get;set;}
    public string P3 {get;set;}
    public string P3 {get;set;}
}

public class Id
{
    public string Main {get;set;}
    public string SubMain {get;set;}
}
```

Having a List I need to return a List with all the pairs P1 - P2 that are different in the List.

So if in the list I have:

```
 P1 = "A" - P2 "B"
 P1 = "A" - P2 "C"
 P1 = "B" - P2 "B"
 P1 = "A" - P2 "B"
```

I need to return a List with 3 Id like:

```
 Main = "A" - SubMain "B"
 Main = "A" - SubMain "C"
 Main = "B" - SubMain "B"
```

Is this possible with just one LINQ query? I would say yes but I'm not very comfortable with the Select statement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried Select with adding the Where condition?

Comment: No idea on how to put a where on two fields requiring a Distinct

Comment: Could you show the linq statement you tried?

Comment: What is the relationship between class `A` and class `Id`?

Comment: Could you give me an example on how to do the LINQ query I need?

Comment: @Jens Kloster: No relation, I need to build the Id instances from the properties on class A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you even don't need to create tuples (I don't like them for ugly item names) for selecting distinct values - anonymous types have built-in Equals and GetHashCode implementations which will be used for distinct selection:

```
list.Select(a => new { a.P1, a.P2 })
    .Distinct()
    .Select(x => new Id { Main = x.P1, SubMain = x.P2 });
```

Comment: I think this solution is slightly better than Cyril's one due to the fact that I reference x.P1 and x.P2 in the second select instead of x.Item1 and x.Item2

Comment: Awesome, forgot about anonymous type, this answer is even better

Answer (score 3):

First create an `IEqualityComparer<A>`, then:

```
class AP1P2Comparer : IEqualityComparer<A>
{

    public bool Equals(A a1, A a2)
    {
        return a1.P1 == a2.P1 && a1.P2 == a2.P2
    }


    public int GetHashCode(A a)
    {
       unchecked 
       {
         int hash = 17;
         hash = hash * 23 + a.T1.GetHashCode();
         hash = hash * 23 + a.T2.GetHashCode();
         return hash;
       }
    }

}
//...
var result = list.Distinct(new AP1P2Comparer())
                 .Select(a => new Id { Main = a.P1, SubMain = a.P2 })
                 .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Tuple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple.aspx) class, it will do all the work on the distincts for you :

```
myList.Select(a => Tuple.Create(a.P1, a.P2))
      .Distinct()
      .Select(tuple => new Id() { Main = tuple.Item1, SubMain = tuple.Item2 } )
      .ToList();
```

The advantage is that Tuple class already override members like Equals, GetHashCode, all you need for performing a Distinct on a collection.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov please reread the question and check the expected results.

Comment: @AhmedKRAIEM sure, I've just read statement `with all the pairs P1 - P2 that are different` as not having distinct pairs, but as `P1` not being equal to `P2`

Comment: Thanks. Tuple usage here was a pretty smart solution (even for a French guy) ;) [Just kidding, I love France]

Comment: @SoMoS : we have our moments. Not often, but it happens :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Enumerable.Except

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.except(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

you need a simple linq query:

```
from a in alist
where a.P1 != a.P2
select new Id() { Main = a.P1, SubMain = a.P2 }
```